# storing a value in a parameter

Tags: java

hi please can anyone tell me how to store some int values in an array

```
public int getStatistics(int teamid) {
    int stats = 0;

    for(int runid = 0; runid < 4; runid++) {
        stats = teams[teamid].getRunTime(runid);
    }
}
```

i am writting a method to retrieve the statistics contained for a team in an array location.it contains 4 values.the team id is an int an is selected by user while the run id brings out the values in each location.my problem is to store the value i have in the stats to a place which can contain for seperate values. example 5,7,8,4

Comment: Both your question and example are not clear, at least to me. could you try and make it clearer?

Comment: are you asking how to declare an array of ints?

Comment: If you're trying to collect a sequence of integers (representing "run times"), are you then intending to fold them together to yield a single integral result? Note that your `getStatistics()` function returns an `int`.

Comment: What's the point of doing `stats = teams[teamid].getRunTime(runid);` in a loop? You will end up with the value of `stats = teams[teamid].getRunTime(3);` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is kinda vague, but it seems like you want your function to generate an array. Based on your code:

```
public int[] getStatistics(int teamid) {
    int stats = 0;
    int[] ret = new int[4];

    for(int runid = 0; runid < 4; runid++) {
        ret[runid] = teams[teamid].getRunTime(runid);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Let me know if this isn't what you want to do. As your code stands, your function requires you to return an int, and you don't return anything. If you're trying to add all the values in the for loop or something comparable, you must ADD these values to stats and then return stats. For instance: stats+=teams[teamid].getRunTime(runid);
 And then: return stats; Also, if you're only running one command in the for loop, you need not use brackets to enclose the command.

Comment: i want to return 4 different vaules for e.g 4,6,6,8

Comment: Thanks vinay the method was meant to be an int so that way i could store my values in the int array.Thank you very much

Comment: Yes. Much easier if you just return an int array. :-) So, if this problem has been solved, check the green check mark near this answer so the question is closed.